# When the imaginary part of a function is zero?

Tags: functions, complex-numbers

Let $z_k=x_k+ i y_k, x_i,y_i \in \mathbb{R}$ are the complex variables. Consider a polynomial of $z_k$ and  its conjugates $f(z_1,\ldots,z_n, \bar{z}_1, \ldots,\bar{z}_n).$

**Question**:Is there any simple criterion to check out if the imaginary part  of $f(z_1,\ldots,z_n, \bar{z}_1, \ldots,\bar{z}_n)$ is  zero  for arbitrary $z_k.$?

Since $\mathfrak{Im}(z_k+\bar{z}_k)=\mathfrak{Im}(z_k\bar{z}_k)=0$  we may assume that the $f$ can be represented as a function of the variables $z_k+\bar{z}_k$  and $z_k\bar{z}_k.$ It it the complete answer on the question?

Comment: To be clear, do you want $\text{Im}(f)$ to be zero everywhere? Or just for the particular choice of $z_1,\dots,z_n$?

Comment: Must be zero everywhere for all $z_1,\ldots,z_n$ like as $(z_1+\bar{z_1})z_2 \bar{z}_2.$

Comment: Just check that the coefficient of each term is equal to the complex conjugate of the coefficient of the conjugated term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take its conjugate. If $\overline{f(z,\bar z)} = f(z,\bar z)$ it is real-valued. Since conjugate is a ring homomorphism it distributes over sums and products.

For instance:
$$
\overline{(z_1+\bar z_1)z_2 \bar z_2}
= (\bar z_1 + z_1) \bar z_2 z_2
$$
so you know it's real-valued.

Comment: Thank you. I see now it was   very easy question :)